# C++ and OpenSSL Library: How can I set subjectAltName (SAN) from code?

Tags: c++, openssl, self-signed-certificate

I'm trying to create self-signed request with subjectAltName from c++ code (trying to implement dynamic self-signed certificates like [this](https://github.com/dutchcoders/lua-nginx-module/commit/08084fa764c2891bb983fa04c0b58914b43384d6)  to actual version of OpenResty, but there is not sollution for subjectAltName).

Please, provide some examples of setting SANs from C++/OpenSSL code. I trying some like this:

```
    X509_EXTENSION  *ext;
    STACK_OF (X509_EXTENSION) * extlist;
    char *ext_name = "subjectAltName";
    char *ext_value = "DNS:lohsport.com";

    extlist = sk_X509_EXTENSION_new_null ();
    ext = X509V3_EXT_conf (NULL, NULL, ext_name, ext_value);
    if(ext == NULL)
    {
        *err = "Error creating subjectAltName extension";
        goto failed;
    }
    sk_X509_EXTENSION_push (extlist, ext);

    if (!X509_REQ_add_extensions (x509_req, extlist)){
        *err = "Error adding subjectAltName to the request";
        goto failed;
    }
    sk_X509_EXTENSION_pop_free (extlist, X509_EXTENSION_free);
```

It's compiling successfully but not works. 
I would be grateful for any help.

**UPDATE**
Now i trying to work as in selfsing.c demo of OpenSSL Library:

1) I defined a function for adding extensions to CSR:

```
int add_ext(STACK_OF(X509_EXTENSION) *sk, int nid, char *value)
{
X509_EXTENSION *ex;
ex = X509V3_EXT_conf_nid(NULL, NULL, nid, value);
if (!ex)
    return 0;
sk_X509_EXTENSION_push(sk, ex);

return 1;
}
```

2) Add this block to my function which generates CSR:

```
   char Buffer[512];
    // Format the value
    sprintf (Buffer, "DNS:%s", info->common_name);
    xts = sk_X509_EXTENSION_new_null();
    add_ext(exts, NID_subject_alt_name, Buffer);

    if(X509_REQ_add_extensions(x509_req, exts) != 1) {
        *err = "X509_REQ_add_extensions() failed";
        goto failed;
    }
    sk_X509_EXTENSION_pop_free(exts, X509_EXTENSION_free);
```

The code again compiles correctly, certificates are generated on the fly, but alternative names still don't work, and I get an error in the browser:

NET :: ERR_CERT_COMMON_NAME_INVALID

and I don’t see the alternative name information in the certificate details.

What other solutions can there be for a SAN problem? I can provide all the code for example on githab if it can help.

Answer (score 1):

Hello I have done something like that (but I am working with `X509` object not `X509_REQ` object like you :

```c
static int cs_cert_set_subject_alt_name(X509 *x509_cert)
{
    char *subject_alt_name = "IP: 192.168.1.1";
    X509_EXTENSION *extension_san = NULL;
    ASN1_OCTET_STRING *subject_alt_name_ASN1 = NULL;
    int ret = -1;

    subject_alt_name_ASN1 = ASN1_OCTET_STRING_new();
    if (!subject_alt_name_ASN1) {
        goto err;
    }
    ASN1_OCTET_STRING_set(subject_alt_name_ASN1, (unsigned char*) subject_alt_name, strlen(subject_alt_name));
    if (!X509_EXTENSION_create_by_NID(&extension_san, NID_subject_alt_name, 0, subject_alt_name_ASN1)) {
        goto err;
    }
    ASN1_OCTET_STRING_free(subject_alt_name_ASN1);
    ret = X509_add_ext(x509_cert, extension_san, -1);
    if (!ret) {
        goto err;
    }
    X509_EXTENSION_free(extension_san);

err:
    if (subject_alt_name_ASN1) ASN1_OCTET_STRING_free(subject_alt_name_ASN1);
    if (extension_san) X509_EXTENSION_free(extension_san);
    return -1;
}
```

It worked for me for the moment, I still have some trouble when I want to update an already existing certificate with a new subject alt name (because of a new ip address).

To see the result and check if the subject alt name is made :

```sh
$ openssl x509 -text -in cert.pem
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `X509V3_EXT_conf` function try with `X509V3_EXT_conf_nid` function in which you pass the NID instead of name.

```
ext = X509V3_EXT_conf (NULL, NULL, ext_name, ext_value);
```

can be

```
ext = X509V3_EXT_conf_nid(NULL, NULL, NID_subject_alt_name, ext_value);
```

Your code might not be working because you might not be exactly matching the extension name with the one in OpenSSL code.

Comment: Thanks for the help. As far as I understand, your remark is correct, but unfortunately this did not solve the problem. Added Update to the issue with the new code, which also does not work: (